# Search for all similar ID's based on subids

Tags: sql

I would like to extract all the duplicate ID's if other column value is filtered.

ex:

```
ID  Subid
100 99
100 91
100 12
200 32
200 33
200 34
200 35
300 88
300 87
300 86
400 78
400 74
400 73
```

If i want to query only for sub id 99, it should check its ID, and all the rows having that ID should display. Here the result should be

```
ID  Subid
100 99
100 91
100 12
```

Appreciate if you could help.

Regards
sharath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `where` condition would do this

```
select * from table1
where ID in (select id from table1 where subid = 99);
```

(OR) convert above subquery to a `self join`

```
select t.* from table1 t
join table1 t1 on t.ID = t1.ID
where t1.subid = 99;
```